# Using Wildcard For Range of Characters In T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, wildcard, sql-server-2016

I'm currently using `REPLACE` to replace the following characters below which may be found in a customers name. However, it's pretty tedious doing it this way.

Would anyone know if there's a way to do this using a list format for example, a wildcard like such: `LIKE ['.',',']` rather than writing replace each time?

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dname,'.',''),'`',''),'''',''),'  ',' ')))
```

Comment: which dbms you are using (mysql, postgresql, tsql / sql-server, oracle)?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I'm using T-SQL

Comment: @user3396351 the best place to clean up this data is the client application, not T-SQL. That said, SQL Server 2016 and later allow you to use R and Python scripts. You could use an R or Python script to clean up the names with a simple regular expression or use text processing and data cleaning packages packages like [janitor](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor)

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If you're on 2016, you have `TRANSLATE`, which might make this a lot easier.

Comment: @Larnu Yes i'm using SQL Server 2016, i'll try out `TRANSLATE`, i've never used that one before

Comment: TRANSLATE was not introduced until SQL SERVER 2017

Comment: @nealkernohan you're absolutely right, so I won't be able to use `TRANSLATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know the version, but if you're only 2016+ `TRANSLATE` would likely work well here:

```
DECLARE @ReplaceChars varchar(50) = '.''`(){}[]!"£$%^&*-=_+';

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(YourColumn, @ReplaceChars, REPLICATE(LEFT(@ReplaceChars, 1), LEN(@ReplaceChars)),LEFT(@ReplaceChars,1),''),'  ',' ')
FROM ...
```

You'll still need to use `REPLACE` on the left most character, and the double spaces though.

Comment: I'm sure this will work, but for some reason it says `'TRANSLATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.` I have SQL Server 2016 running on SSMS 17, I researched online and apparently other people have the same problem with using`TRANSLATE` on SSMS17

Comment: It's not an SSMS issue, @user3396351 . SSMS has no effect on how a query will behave on the Data Engine; it's purely a interaction and presentation layer. What compatibility level is your database in? it needs to be 130 or higher.

Comment: @user3396351 SSMS is just a client tool. It doesn't affect what can or can't be used in a database

Comment: @Larnu the compatibility level i'm currently on is set to 110

Comment: And there is your problem then @user3396351 . 110 is SQL Server 2012 levels, and `TRANSLATE` won't work there. You'll be back to nested `REPLACE` statements if you can't change the level.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, unfortunately I can't change the level, but since your answer would essentially resolve my query i'll mark it as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For this type of thing I would go with [PatExclude8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/patexclude8k). It's not scalar, 100% set-based and nasty fast.

To remove non-alphanumeric from this string:

```
SELECT f.* FROM dbo.PatExclude8K('ABC123!!!   ???','[^A-Z0-9]') AS f;
```

**Returns:** ABC123

Return only the numbers from values table:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (someid INT IDENTITY, somestring VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @table (somestring) 
SELECT TOP (10) NEWID() FROM sys.all_columns;

SELECT t.someid, t.somestring, pe.NewString
FROM  @table AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(t.somestring,'[^0-9]') AS pe
```

**Returns:**

```
someid      somestring                                NewString
----------- ----------------------------------------- ---------------------------
1           2FEF1D43-1A85-456D-BF9E-B329AD64A980      2143185456932964980
2           EB73205F-84C8-407E-8D4F-66FAFD1F556B      7320584840784661556
3           5BEA68B1-783B-4F57-A24D-CF110ADECFEA      568178345724110
4           FC7466E3-5CB8-4DDD-B7F0-30A539DF7C02      746635847030539702
5           800E3AC3-257F-4FF5-B7EE-E6B9268B5608      80033257457692685608
6           A1C33269-48EC-4100-A691-0EA9F2C55E21      1332694841006910925521
7           9C19F844-FE71-40BE-BFFF-276FE344B171      9198447140276344171
8           08529640-E77E-44AD-93A9-E69CE92AF1BD      08529640774493969921
9           FBADC1AE-ED96-4A0E-B106-C6C34E34A612      1964010663434612
10          7E52CFC5-025E-431B-99C1-589E957726B5      75250254319915899577265
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with customer names then you really should be using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` since you cannot guarantee that names will only ever have US English characters (i.e. "A" - "Z") plus some assorted accented characters (I assume you are using the default collation which is `*Latin1_General*`, which in turn uses code page 1252 for `VARCHAR` data).

That said, there are *a lot* of characters that are valid in names (typically letters, but also hyphens and commas), and *a lot* of characters that are invalid. Trying to specify either group, even as a series of characters in a character class (i.e. `[...]`) is something that could require updating every time a new one comes through.

One easy way to handle this is to use Regular Expressions (i.e. RegEx, and no, the `[...]` wildcard of the `LIKE` and `PATINDEX` functions is *not* a Regular Expression, no matter how many people refer to it as such). SQL Server does not natively support RegEx, but you can get that functionality via SQLCLR, which works in all on-prem editions (including SQL Server on Linux) for all versions starting with 2005, and Azure SQL Database Managed Instances; it is only unavailable on the regular Azure SQL Database and AWS SQL Server RDS (starting with version 2017). An easy way to get RegEx is to download and install [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_57529450), a SQLCLR library that I created (and most of the RegEx functions are in the Free version, including what I will use below).

Regular Expressions not only handle complex patterns (far more complex than we are dealing with here), but they also allow us to specify Unicode "categories". For this particular case, we just need to use the "Letter" category, which includes upper-case, lower-case, and other forms of letters. Using this category alone will also remove hyphens and commas, and since we probably don't want to do that (as they are valid in names), we can easily add those back in.

The expression we will use is: `[^\p{L}, -]`. This pattern is read as:

- `[^...]` = find any single character that does *not* match the characters in this list
- `\p{L}`  = match any character categorized as a "Letter" (in *any* language, which is why this just works)
- `, -` = match commas, spaces, and hyphens. Since hyphens are used in character classes to indicate ranges, they need to be either the first or last character if meant to be used as a literal hyphen.

And that brings us to the following example:

```
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(
            N'a    .`     ''b$c   d  ef-ghi,jr. ꓤ ඖ  ל ؼ ញ z', -- string to modify
            N'[^\p{L}, -]',   -- regular expression (pattern)
            N'',              -- replacement
            -1,               -- number of occurrences to replace (-1 = unlimited)
            1,                -- character position to start at
            NULL              -- RegEx options (such as case-insensitive, multi-line, etc)
       );

 --a         bc   d  ef-ghi,jr ꓤ ඖ  ל ؼ ញ z
```

Of course, this still leaves us with one issue that no other answer has (correctly) addressed: converting multiple spaces into a single space.

In the question you have a `REPLACE` set up to convert two spaces into a single space. That will only work if there are *only* two spaces. If there are three or more spaces, then it only converts every group of two, which will still leave you with multiple spaces. For example:

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'a   b', N'  ', N' ') AS [3 spaces],
       REPLACE(N'a    b', N'  ', N' ') AS [4 spaces],
       REPLACE(N'a     b', N'  ', N' ') AS [5 spaces];

/*
3 spaces    4 spaces    5 spaces
a  b        a  b        a   b
*/
```

As you can see, the "3" and "4" space tests both left two spaces, while the "5" spaces test left three spaces.

Here is another type of operation that RegEx is well suited for. You can specify a pattern to match on "two or more spaces" and then it will handle any number of spaces and replace whatever it matched with a single space, whether it was 2, 3, or 27 spaces. We can use a pattern of either `\s{2,}` which means "two or more white-space characters", or `\s\s+` which means "a white-space character followed by one-or-more white-space characters".

For example, if we start with the output of the previous RegEx test, we can do the following:

```
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(
           N'a         bc   d  ef-ghi,jr ꓤ ඖ  ל ؼ ញ z', N'\s{2,}',
           N' ',
           -1, 1, NULL);

--a bc d ef-ghi,jr ꓤ ඖ ל ؼ ញ z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a regular expression within a function, to remove or include the characters you want.

e.g.

`Create Function [dbo].[AlphaCharactersOnly](@str VarChar(MAX))
Returns VarChar(MAX)
AS
Begin
    Declare @strKeep as varchar(MAX)
    Set @strKeep = '%[^ ^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@strKeep, @str) > 0
        Set @str = Stuff(@str, PatIndex(@strKeep, @str), 1, '')
    Return @str
End`

Comment: A combination of a scalar function and a `WHILE` is likely going to make a very poor performing query.