# attempting a replace function on sql but with wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

this is my first time posting so hopefully I get all the information needed across correctly.

I'm attempting to do an update replace statement on a row where there is a set of characters but a wildcard statement won't work, below is a select statement example

```
SELECT replace(column, '[aA][bB][cC]-', '')
FROM table
where column like '%[aA][bB][cC]-%'
```

an example row would be "abc-123 aBc-123 abC-abc Def-123", but I need it to return "123 123 abc"

this is a basic example, but I'm trying to get rid of a set of 3 characters and a "-" character anywhere in a string. the abc could change to def but the "-" character will always come after.

I've done some googling and can't find an appropriate solution as most examples will only remove one example of abc- where I need to get rid of all versions. I'm running version 12.0 of sql server (SQL Server 2014) so I think some functions I wouldn't be able to use.

I think the closest example I could find was [Using Wildcard For Range of Characters In T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522784/using-wildcard-for-range-of-characters-in-t-sql) but I can't use the translate function.

Edit: below is an example of a created table

```
 CREATE TABLE String_Removal_Example( 
someValue VARCHAR(100) 
) 
INSERT INTO String_Removal_Example (someValue) VALUES ('abc-123') 
INSERT INTO String_Removal_Example (someValue) VALUES ('abc-123 ABC-123') 
INSERT INTO String_Removal_Example (someValue) VALUES ('abc-123 ABc-123 123-ABC DEF-123')
```

select statement brings back

```
someValue
abc-123
abc-123 ABC-123
abc-123 ABc-123 123-ABC DEF-123
```

Edit2: If this isn't possible to do in this manner, a possible alternative would be to remove 3 characters and the - character. I've tried the below

```
select Substring (someValue, Charindex( '-', someValue ) + 1, Len(someValue)) From String_Removal_Example
```

but this returns the below, which is only affecting the first instance of nnn-.

```
123
123 ABC-123
123 ABc-123 123-ABC DEF-123
```

Edit3: The string I need to replace is nnn- for clarification. I was trying for the [aA][bB][cC]- format in case I needed to change it. It will always be 3 characters followed by a "-" Character

Comment: Doesn't `replace(column, 'abc-', '')` work? You may have to use case insensitive collation.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also specify the expected result. (It's not clear as it is now. [mcve].)

Comment: @Arvo - It will work if it was only for abc-, but the string could have Abc- or def- for example, i need to get all variations.

Comment: @jarhl I've updated the question with an example table, hopefully this helps?

Comment: I think its just a matter of collation, does this work? SELECT REPLACE(somevalue COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 'abc-','') FROM String_Removal_Example

Comment: @JamesCasey Hi Thanks that does work, the letters might change. Sorry I should have been more clear on this, apologies its the first time I've done this. The rows might also contain aDC-123 which is why I was looking for [a][b][c]- as the replacement string in case I needed to change it. I'll amend the question.

Comment: I've posted an answer which might work for you. Its probably worth noting that given how terrible SQL is at string manipulation, it might be better to just store it as it is and have the application layer handle it (or have whatever is inserting handle it). Its also possible you should have a separate table with multiple rows rather than storing them all in one string like that

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you have 4 characters?  e.g. `ABCD-123`, should this be ignored because it is more than 3 characters, or should this still replace the 3 characters and the hyphen to leave `A123`? What if the 3 characters before contained non alphanumeric characters, e.g. `A&c-123`, again, should this be ignored or should it return `123`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XML trick that'll also work in Sql Server 2014

*(In Sql Server 2016 and beyond, the [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function would be better.)*

> ```
> declare @String_Removal_Example table ( 
>  someValue varchar(100) not null
> );
>
> insert into @String_Removal_Example (someValue) VALUES 
>   ('abc-123') 
> , ('abc-123 ABC-123') 
> , ('abc-123 ABC-123 123-Abc DEF-123');
>
> select ca.value as someValue
> from @String_Removal_Example t
> cross apply 
> (
>   select rtrim((
>     select node.n.value('.','varchar(30)')+' '
>     from 
>     (
>       select cast('<x><a>' + replace(replace(t.someValue, 
>                   ' ', '</n><a>'), 
>                   '-', '</a><n>') +
>                   '</n></x>' as xml) as x
>     ) q
>     cross apply x.nodes ('/x/n') AS node(n)
>     for xml path('') 
>    )) as value
> ) ca
> where lower(t.someValue) like '%[a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]%';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | someValue       |
> | :-------------- |
> | 123             |
> | 123 123         |
> | 123 123 Abc 123 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=41c603f73c84c42745291a1548b1e249)*

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: With all the hoopla around it, the `STRING_SPLIT()` function doesn't guarantee sequential order. It makes it unusable for the case.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky That's only when the order matters. Doubt that's the case here. Also, look at the defenition of string_split. Maybe MS will add that ordinal flag one day in regular Sql Server.

Comment: You are right on target. It is a very old request: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5eaf994d-4025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: FYI It looks like the ordinal has been added to the functionality, but is only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics - [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#enable_ordinal)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this:
(I named it `ThreeLetters`, but what's in a name...)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ThreeLetters] 
(
    @p0 VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(20) = '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-%';
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX) = @p0;
    DECLARE @pos INT = PATINDEX(@p1,@Result COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS);
    DECLARE @pos2 INT ;
    DECLARE @i INT =0;

    WHILE @pos>0 and @i<10
    BEGIN
       SET @pos2 = CHARINDEX('-',@Result,@pos)-@pos;
       SELECT @Result = SUBSTRING(@Result,1,@pos-1)+SUBSTRING(@Result, @pos+@pos2+1, len(@Result));
       SET @pos = PATINDEX(@p1,@Result COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS);
       SET @i = @i + 1;
    END 
    RETURN @Result
END
```

output with your sample data:

| someValue | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| abc-123 | 123 |
| abc-123 ABC-123 | 123 123 |
| abc-123 ABc-123 123-ABC DEF-123 | 123 123 123-ABC 123 |

see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be813d45f0e480abd423c659efe67bc3)

P.S. The check for `@i` was introduced while debugging. It might not be needed, but was tooo lazy to remove it.

P.P.S  I am removing ThreeLetters followed by a `-`, that is why `123-ABC` remains unchanged.

Comment: Hello Luuk I was able to get what I needed from this solution. Thank you very much. I was able to amend this a bit to work about the [def] part of my problem. Would upvote but I need to have 15 reputation. Edit: Now I can. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution. It is a variation of @LukStorms solution.

It is based on XML and XQuery. Their data model is based on *ordered sequences*.

XML allows us to tokenize the input string.

It is looking for 'nnn-' strings and filters them out.

For example, 2nd row is converted to XML like this:

```
<root>
  <r>abc-</r>
  <r>123</r>
  <r>ABC-</r>
  <r>123</r>
</root>
```

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
declare @String_Removal_Example table ( 
 someValue varchar(100) not null
);
insert into @String_Removal_Example (someValue) VALUES 
  ('abc-123') 
, ('abc-123 ABC-123') 
, ('abc-123 ABC-123 123-Abc DEF-123');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT someValue AS [before], [after]
FROM @String_Removal_Example
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
         REPLACE(REPLACE(someValue, '-', '- '), SPACE(1), ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
         ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
    .query('data(/root/r[not(contains(text()[1],"-"))])')
    .value('.','VARCHAR(255)')) AS t1(after);
```

**Output**

```
+---------------------------------+-----------------+
|             before              |      after      |
+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| abc-123                         | 123             |
| abc-123 ABC-123                 | 123 123         |
| abc-123 ABC-123 123-Abc DEF-123 | 123 123 Abc 123 |
+---------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT replaceAll(column, '[aA][bB][cC]-', '')
FROM table
where column like '%[aA][bB][cC]-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically dividing up the string where there are spaces, then looking for "words" that have a '-' in the 4th position, removing the prefix and then stitching it back together:

```
SELECT s.someValue,
    STUFF((SELECT ' ' + SUBSTRING(value, 5, LEN(value) - 4)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(someValue, ' ') 
             WHERE CHARINDEX('-', value) = 4 
             FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') a
FROM String_Removal_Example s
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no regex replace in SQL Server, I think the only way you can reliably use a pattern replace is through an iterative process. One such way is with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  SomeValue
    FROM (VALUES 
            ('abc-123'), 
            ('abc-123 ABC-123'), 
            ('abc-123 aBc-123 abC-abc Def-123'),
            ('abc-123 ABCD-123'), 
            ('abc-123 A$C-123')
        ) x (SomeValue)
), RegexReplace AS
(   SELECT  SomeValue, NewValue = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Data.SomeValue), Level = 1
    FROM    Data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SomeValue, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), STUFF(NewValue, PATINDEX('% [A-z][A-z][A-z]-%', CONCAT(' ', NewValue)), 4, '')), Level + 1
    FROM    RegexReplace AS d
    WHERE   PATINDEX('% [A-z][A-z][A-z]-%', CONCAT(' ', NewValue)) > 0
), RankedData AS
(   SELECT  *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rr.SomeValue ORDER BY rr.Level DESC)
    FROM    RegexReplace AS rr
)
SELECT  rd.SomeValue, rd.NewValue
FROM    RankedData AS rd
WHERE   rd.RowNumber = 1;
```

Which gives:

| SomeValue | New Value |
| --- | --- |
| abc-123 | 123 |
| abc-123 ABC-123 | 123 123 |
| abc-123 aBc-123 abC-abc Def-123 | 123 123 abc 123 |
| abc-123 A$C-123 | 123 A$C-123 |
| abc-123 ABCD-123 | 123 ABCD-123 |

This basically uses [`PATINDEX()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to find the first instance of the pattern, then [`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to remove the 4 characters after the index found. This process then repeats until the `PATINDEX()` fails to find a match.

Probably also of note is that when doing the `PATINDEX()` I am adding a space to the start of the string, and including a space at the start of the pattern. This ensures that it is limited to only 3 characters followed by a hyphen, if it is more than 3 (e.g. ABCD-123) the entire string is left intact rather than leaving `A123` as shown in the last row above. Adding the space to the start of the string being searched ensures that the pattern is still found even if it is at the start of the string.